# Can you write your own customized allennlp command?

Tags: allennlp

I want to create a new train command for allennlp. Is it possible to run it with "allennlp my_own_command" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues/5164.